# Combining a select statement of boolean

Tags: sql, db2

Hi guys could you please help me out here.

```sql
SELECT e.name, 
    IF  e.active = 0 THEN
      e.active = true
   WHERE e.id = #{estate_id}
    ELSE 
      e.active = false
   WHERE e.id = #{estate_id}
   END IF
   AS Estate_status
   FROM estates e
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 5):

This is db2 syntax as you have not mentioned which DB you are using:

```
select e.name,
    case when e.active = 0 then 'TRUE'
        else 'FALSE'
    end AS Estate_status,
    from estates e
where e.id = #{estate_id}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` statement :

```sql
SELECT
  e.name, 
  (case when e.active = 0 THEN e.active = 1 ELSE e.active = 0 END) AS Estate_status
FROM 
  estates e
WHERE
  e.id = #{estate_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by the rest of your SQL statement. What exactly are you trying to achieve.

However, in regard to the question itself, you can't use an IF statement within the SQL like that. You can however use a CASE statment, such as:

```
CASE
    WHEN e.active = 0 THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
END
```